# Incrementing a nested list element

Tags: list-manipulation

I've been wanting to increment a nested list element of which I know the "coordinates". I thought of the following procedure, using Apply with Part.

```
test = Table[10 h + 5 i + j, {h, 0, 3}, {i, 0, 1}, {j, 0, 4}];
pos = {4, 2, 3};
Increment[test[[##]] & @@ pos];
```

Yet it seems that `test[[##]] & @@ pos` is treated like a different variable. When I print

```
test[[##]] & @@ pos
test
```

I can see that `test[[##]] & @@ pos` gives an incremented result, but `test` itself is not changed. What would be a nice and efficient way of incrementing a nested list element, saving the new value of the whole list ?

### Edit

So in the light of the first comments, let me say more about what I would like to achieve :

I have a nested list `test` which can be of any depth. I have a list `pos` whose length is equal to

```
Depth[test]-1
```

The goal is to increment the element at the position `pos` in `test` (I guess by using `Apply`) and return the incremented nested list. My method below increments well but then does not store the new value in the list.

Comment: `test[[pos]]=test[[pos]] + 1` ?

Comment: what do you want your final result to look like?

Comment: `test[[pos]]` does not work because pos is a `list`. I would like my final result to be the same nested list but with one of the element (given by ´pos`) incremented by one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
test[[Sequence@@pos]]++
```

Comment: Works and returns the incremented list ! Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 5):

Why to go through the hustle defining pos manually and then using `@@` ? With the same effort you can just put coordinates explicitly inside `[[...]]`

```
test[[4, 2, 3]]++
```

Comment: The idea is to do it dynamically for plenty of `pos`. And technically `test` can be of any dimension, and `pos` should be of the corresponding length.

Comment: @Pschoofs Could you please show then the more general use/goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Check the edit, I hope I could explain myself a little better ;)

Comment: @Pschoofs thanks for the update. But I think if you can define and dynamically update `pos` as a separate statement, you can also easily do it inside `[[...]]` too ;-)

Answer (score 4):

If you "must" use `Apply` you can use it as

```
Increment[test[[##]]] & @@ pos
(* 37 *)
```

or

```
test[[##]]++ & @@ pos
(* 37 *)
```

which gives

```
test
(* {{{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}},
   {{10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, {15, 16, 17, 18, 19}}, 
   {{20, 21, 22, 23, 24}, {25, 26, 27, 28, 29}},
   {{30, 31, 32, 33, 34}, {35, 36, 38, 38, 39}}} *)
```